# What does the map for SynonymType.entities look like?

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

I can't seem to figure out how to actually create a synonym for Google Assistant to map `labels` and `label` to `label` when answering a query.

Here's my type file:

```yaml
synonym:
  # matchType: FUZZY_MATCH
  acceptUnknownValues: false
  entities:
    label:
```

Unfortunately, the value of `intent.params.{fieldName}.resolved` continues to map to `labels` (plural) when spoken as a plural phrase.  The documentation doesn't specify what the map for entities should look like.

Documentation links:

- https://developers.google.com/assistant/actionssdk/reference/rest/Shared.Types/Type
- https://developers.google.com/assistant/actionssdk/reference/rest/Shared.Types/SynonymType

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this example: https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-builder-facts-about-google-nodejs/blob/master/sdk/custom/types/fact_category.yaml

Google Assistant SDK `SynonymType` should look like this:

```yaml
synonym:
  entities:
    'resolved value':
      synonyms:
      - 'proposed match 1'
      - 'proposed match 2'
      - 'proposed match 3'
  matchType: EXACT_MATCH
```